# How do I properly change a level value based on a specific value of another column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, recode

I want to change/recode the levels for a column based on a specific value of the same column and another column. As an example, let's use ggplot2::diamonds. In this scenario, I want to change the value of "Premium" in the ***cut*** column to "Perfect" if the column ***color*** is "D" and change the value of "Premium" to "Amazing" if column ***color*** is "J". This is my attempt:

```
df <- ggplot2::diamonds
unique(df$cut) #to look at the initial values


df$cut <- with(df,ifelse(cut == "Premium" & color == "D", "Perfect", 
                      ifelse(cut== "Premium" & color == "J","Amazing", cut)))
```

The issue is that when looking at the cut column afterwards, the other values have also been changed.

```
unique(df$cut)

[1] "5"       "4"       "2"       "3"       "1"       "Perfect" "Amazing"
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? If there are other ways than how I attempted to do this, I would also appreciate seeing that as well!

Answer (score 1):

Using `case_when()`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(cut = 
           as.factor(case_when(
    (cut == "Premium" & color == "D") ~ "Perfect",
    (cut == "Premium" & color == "J") ~ "Amazing",
    TRUE  ~ as.character(cut))
  )
  ) 

unique(df$cut)
```

Output:

```
[1] Ideal     Premium   Good      Very Good Fair      Perfect   Amazing  
Levels: Amazing Fair Good Ideal Perfect Premium Very Good
```

Answer (score 0):

I often use this `base` R method:

```
df$cut <- as.character(df$cut)

df$cut[df$color == "D" & df$cut == "Premium" ] <-  "Perfect"
df$cut[df$color == "J" & df$cut == "Premium" ] <-  "Amazing"

df$cut <- as.ordered(df$cut)
```

But you have to turn your factor to character first, or you will get an error.